# I put my phone on airplane mode before I sent a text but it's still trying to deliver

Tags: iphone, ios

I accidentally sent my boyfriend a video, I had the ugliest laugh in it and I'd rather have him never hear it. I quickly put my phone on airplane mode but I never got the option to cancel the message like I used to. If I just delete the text will it never deliver or is that not how it works?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply delete the video message that was in progress of being sent and it will not be delivered.